# Is it still possible to get all posts a user has liked on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

In the graph api (v2.12) "me/likes" returns all the public pages a user has liked (with the user_likes permission). However, I also want to access all posts a user has liked. I have read that "og.likes" could be used for this but this returns an empty list. Does anyone know whether it is still possible to get all posts a user has liked on Facebook and if so how (which call and which permission do I need)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope, not possible. And any attempts at getting even a fraction of the data (like going through posts of liked pages and also app-using friends) would be way to costly.

Comment: This question is probably better answered in the Facebook's docs. But shouldn't be possible, at least they've been paying more attention to user's privacy, depending on your access key.

Comment: Allright, thank you for your replies! It is a good thing that they are paying more attention to user's privacy, but by typing in "posts liked by [username]" in the search bar on Facebook you do get to see (part of) the likes...